# Hot-side and Cold-side rechargeable chemical compound

Tags: electrochemistry, heat, applied-chemistry

I am wondering if such a chemical/material exists which, upon triggering, becomes cold on one side and hot on the other in which after all the chemical bonds are broken/built (however it would work), and the chemical begins to move towards thermal equilibrium, it could be 'recharged' using electricity?

What I am investigating is an effect similar to that of the 'Peltier' effect in which one side of a semi-conducting material becomes very cold and the other side very hot! These devices are horribly inefficient though.

Comment: It's possible, basically if you have a normal battery-like redox, but with one side being endothermic. I don't know of any case where that happens to a notable degree, though. I doubt any such reaction would be more efficient than Peltiers.

Comment: Recharging works via heating, not electricity, but the self-cooling beer keg has been on the market for quite a while. Check your friendly search engine. ;-)